# How to define a vector with a variable size in C++

Tags: c++, vector

How to define a vector with dynamic array size. I don't know the size of the vector from the beginning and I need to have a dynamic vector like V[i] not V[10] or V[13] !! I need dynamic vector like V[i] how can I do that?

Thx

Comment: Here is an idea - read the manual - vectors are dynaic - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> numbers; //this is a dynamic vector of int

  numbers.push_back(3);
  numbers.push_back(102);
  //add as many more as you need
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> How to define a vector with dynamic array size.

You mean you know how big the vector is going to be at runtime, but not at compile-time?

```
int n = your_size_computation_here();
std::vector<int> a(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<type>
```

The type is documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::vector`, which is a dynamic container.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/